# app not receiving background notification signal in ios14

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{}
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
    didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
             withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {}
```

These 2 methods do not work at all when the application is in state. Incoming message with payload content-available = 1 not done, i have no problem where, i followed apple instructions, 13 versions i all work fine but with ios 14 again are not. please help me

Comment: So is there any method by which I can receive silent notifications while in background on ios 14

Comment: Silent remote notifications are delivered on `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. If not there’s something wrong with your setup.

Comment: I don't see any response when silent notifications are sent with content-available = 1. didReceivedRomoteNotification doesn't seem to work in the background for OS versions 14.7.1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To make it easier to help you, please add more details about your setup and how to reproduce the problem you're facing. I know that notifications still work in iOS14. So: what exactly should trigger the notification? How do you test it? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Also: what do you mean with "...when the application is in state".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{} 
message apns-push-type = background, on ios 14, i see absolutely no sign of implementation on that method?